# TikZ Drawing a changing vector field in a grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

So far I succeeded in drawing a simple grid along with it's centres using grid and nodes.

```
\draw[step=1] (0, 0) grid (4, 3);

\coordinate (a) at (0.4, 0.3);
\coordinate (b) at (3.8, 0.8);

\draw[fill=white,thick,->] (a) -- (b);

\foreach \x in {0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5} {
    \foreach \y in {0.5, 1.5, 2.5} {
        \node at (\x, \y)[circle, fill=black, scale=0.25] {};
    }
}
```

However the nodes representing the centroids of the cells, I would also like to add a vector field. The vectors in a column should point in the same direction, but along the x axis they should point more in the upward direction as one goes to the right side (like Pi/8, Pi/4, 3*Pi/4, etc). It's clear to me how this would be programmed in a "normal" programming language, but I don't see how this fits into TikZ's foreach loop..

Also I'm wondering weather it's possible to have a curvilinear grid instead of a simple rectangular.

Comment: What I find really confusing that I couldn't figure out how to define scalar variables, just vectors?!

Comment: Can you sketch what you mean by a "curvilinear grid" and post the image?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Curvilinear_grid.svg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` on the preamble.  Then use something like

```
\foreach \x in {0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5} {
    \foreach \y in {0.5, 1.5, 2.5} {
        \node at (\x, \y)[circle, fill=black, scale=0.25] {};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\vx}{0.2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\vy}{\x*0.2}
        \draw[->] (\x,\y) -- (\x+\vx, \y+\vy);
    }
}
```

Replace the expressions for `\vx` and `\vy` according to the mathematical expression you wish to use.  If necessary you can also use trigonometric functions or other standard mathematical functions.

Comment: Soo.. \vx is a scalar?

Comment: @Nils: yes, it is.  You can set separately `\vx` and `\vy`, the two components of your vector field along x and y.

Comment: Note that the multiplication sign (in the def of \vy) is necessary. Took me a while to figure that out as in normal calc uses it's not required.

Answer (score 20):

pgfplots can draw vector fields by means of its `quiver` plot handler.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title=Quiver and plot table]
    \addplot[blue,
        quiver={u=\thisrow{u},v=\thisrow{v}},
        -stealth]
    table
    {
    x y u v
    0 0 1 0
    1 1 1 1
    2 4 1 4
    3 9 1 6
    4 16 1 8
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={$x \exp(-x^2-y^2)$ and its gradient},
        domain=-2:2,
        view={0}{90},
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
    ]
        \addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=9,
            labels=false},thick]
                {exp(0-x^2-y^2)*x};
        \addplot3[blue,
            quiver={
             u={exp(0-x^2-y^2)*(1-2*x^2)},
             v={exp(0-x^2-y^2)*(-2*x*y)},
             scale arrows=0.3,
            },
            -stealth,samples=15]
                {exp(0-x^2-y^2)*x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

It is restricted to rectangular grids, log coords or polar coords, though.

Answer (score 16):

To iterate variables "simultaneously" `TikZ` has the following syntax: the list of variables must be separated by slashes `/`, and the list items can also be lists of values separated by slashes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) grid (4, 3);

\foreach \x/\angle in {0.5/20, 1.5/40, 2.5/60, 3.5/80} {
    \foreach \y in {0.5, 1.5, 2.5} {
        \fill (\x,\y) circle[radius=1pt];
        \draw[->,thick]  (\x, \y) -- ++(\angle:1);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: here's a modified version using multiples of an angle expressed in radians:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\angle{pi/8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dang}{deg(\angle)}
\draw (0, 0) grid (4, 3);

\foreach \x/\k in {0.5/1, 1.5/2, 2.5/3, 3.5/4} {
    \foreach \y in {0.5, 1.5, 2.5} {
        \fill (\x,\y) circle[radius=1pt];
        \draw[->,thick]  (\x, \y) -- ++(\k*\dang:1);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you also specify the angle in rad using a constant symbol for PI?

Comment: @Nils: `pgf` uses degrees (for hopefully obvious reasons) but the accompanying `pgfmath` package includes functions that translate between degrees and radians.  So you would have to do the requisite conversion.  `\pgfmathsetmacro{\dang}{deg(\angle)}` would do.

Comment: Gonzalo: One bit I changed was to use `\fill (\x,\y) circle[radius=1pt];` for the circles.  Just because one _can_ draw nodes with circles doesn't mean that one _should_.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers/comment, I think the key is to use pgf math :)

Comment: @Nils: I've updated my answer with a second example using multiples of an angle in radians.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Thx, but it doesn't seem to work here "! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this radius."

Comment: @Nils: perhaps you are using an outdated version of PGF/TikZ? Try changing `\fill (\x,\y) circle[radius=1pt];` to the old syntax `\fill (\x,\y) circle (1pt);` (Of course, update your LaTeX installation when you can).

Comment: thx works, btw I figured out that you can write foreach[count=\blah] and then blah is incremented every time..

Comment: ..or could write currently it doesn't work :(