# How to draw a 2D vector field in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm pretty new to LaTeX and I need to draw a 2D vector field (Like a graph with vector arrows all over it. I can't find it anywhere online. I'd like to use pgfplots if that's possible.

Comment: You may find [this answer to a similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30158/59109) useful. By the way, welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 4):

If you're not stuck to `pgfplots`, `pst-plot` has a `\psVectorfield` command which makes it very easy (adapted from an example in the pst-plot documentation):

```
\documentclass[x11names, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
%
%%%%%%%%%%% v(x, y) = =x² + y² - 1
\psset{unit=4cm, arrowinset=0.12}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.2,-1.2)(1.1,1.1)
    \psaxes[ticksize=0 4pt,axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=inner,subticks=20,
    Ox=-1,Oy=-1](-1,-1)(1,1)
    \psset{arrows=->,algebraic}
    \psVectorfield[linecolor=DarkOliveGreen3](-0.9,-0.9)(0.9,0.9){ x²+y²-1 }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I still can't get it to work for me. This is the command I typed in:
\begin{pspicture}(-1.2,-1.2)(1.1,1.1)
    \psaxes[ticksize=0 4pt,axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=inner,subticks=20,
    Ox=-1,Oy=-1](-1,-1)(1,1)
    \psVectorfield[linecolor=DarkOliveGreen3](-0.9,-0.9)(0.9,0.9){ x^2+y^2-1 }
\end{pspicture}

Comment: To compile pstricks code with `pdflatex`, you have to launch the compiler with the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX).

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to type in latex form on this page so my comment looks like a mess

Comment: You forgot to add the command  `\psset{arrows=->,algebraic}` after `\psaxes`. The normal mode in postscript for computations is `reverse polish notation`,  not `infix` notation.

Comment: I've tried everything but it's just not working for me. I even copypasted everything you had into a new latex document and it didn't work.
But luckily I found a solution. I'm now using the Desmos vector field generator and using my snipping tool, and inserting that as a picture.

Comment: Strange… Did you try compiling just my code (which is a full compilable document)?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: ‘Doesn't work’ means what? What does the .log file say?